# Adding scripts to wp_footer() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Can someone please guide me on how can I add and call all scripts from wp_footer() function?

Answer (score 0):

It's not good choice to add all scripts to footer.

Why? Because in the body many of plugins, themes may use some scripts, which expected to use some js libraries from the header. And if you'll execute all scripts after that codes, you'll get '**red**' console with a lot of not working code.

If your goal is to make first rendering of your website faster, you can use plugins for it, or go to code and removing/replacing some scripts after tests.

But if you need it, here is code to delete script executing from header and move all scripts, which hooked to header

```
function remove_head_scripts() {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);

    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_head_scripts' );
```

This code don't migrate the scripts, which are executing using `echo`,`print_r` or just wrapped into html of website.